# Bootstrap 4 hamburger menu, submenu with back option for mobile view

Tags: bootstrap-4

when we click hamburger menu it will show picture 1 to show all the menus
and when click menu2 it will show its sub menus as in the picture 2.,

I want them to use 100% of the screen width for mobile view only

[image]

As I'm new to design, please share me some sample demo link

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried!

Comment: Hi @VenkateshSivagurunathan, Welcome to [so]. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] with [mcve] before asking a question

Comment: And we don't recommend or share links here. You have to google it

Answer (score 0):

This can be done various ways.

Option 1 : Using `.w-100` - https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_utilities.asp

Option 2 : Using bootstrap grid with row and col and using 
`.col-*, .col-sm-*,.col-md-*,.col-lg-*,.col-xl-*` replacing * with number of grids it should take. - https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp

Option 3 : Using Flexbox - https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_flex.asp

For more detailed response, it would be great, if you can provide additional details of specific issue that you ran into and code, if any, that you have tired.